# JIT tailwindcss using variable in bg-[] not rendering color

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

when passing my color as props like this `<List text="something" color="#84AB86" /> and using in the code className={'bg-[${color}] '} it does not render properly.`

when looking at chrome dev tools color are added correctly like this `bg-[#84AB86]`

while putting the color manually without taking it from props, it does work correctly

after more testing it seems not possible either to do it like this

```
const color = "#84CC79"
className={`bg-[${color}]`}
```

any idea why

Comment: Pretty sure because JIT uses same mechanic as PurgeCSS. So as Tailwind site says about purging (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production) - As long as a class name appears in your template in its entirety, PurgeCSS will not remove it. In your case there is no class `bg-[#84CC79]` in your template itself - this class was rendered by Next. Check your compiled CSS class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use dynamic classes **with JIT Tailwind** you either need to use `safelist` config key or create stub file where you list all your dynamic classes that you will use.

Config example:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'bg-red-500',
    'text-3xl',
    'lg:text-4xl',
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Or make `safelist.txt` in your `src` folder, then add classes there just like so:

```
bg-[#84AB86]
bg-[#fffeee]

// etc..
```

And don't forget to include this `safelist.txt` file to your config `content` so tailwind could watch it.

[Explanation from tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#known-limitations)

If you are **not using JIT**, then you can use `safelist` option for PurgeCSS:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    // Configure as you need
    content: ['./src/**/*.html'],
    // These options are passed through directly to PurgeCSS
    options: {
      // List your classes here, or you can even use RegExp
      safelist: ['bg-red-500', 'px-4', /^text-/],
      blocklist: [/^debug-/],
      keyframes: true,
      fontFace: true,
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above tailwind engine In order to render a custom class dynamicaly:

Does not like:

```js
className={`bg-[${custom-color}]-100`}
```

It expects:

```js
const customBgColorLight = 'bg-custom-color-100';

className={`${customBgColorLight} .....`}
```

For this to work properly you have to include the name of the class in the `safelist:[]` in your `tailwind.config.js`.
For tailwind v.3

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  safelist: [
    'bg-custom-color-500', // your-custom-css-class
    'text-custom-color-500',
    'border-custom-color-500',
    ..... // other classes
    'hover:bg-custom-color-500', // *** also include it with the selector if needed *** 
    .... // other classes
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'custom-color': { // you have to use quotes if key is not in camelCase format
          100: '#d6d6d6',
          500: '#5E8EA2',
          .....          //other variants
        },
        ......           // other colors
```

So you can use it:

```js
// if you want store the values to an object
  const yourClassObj = {
    customBgColor: 'bg-custom-color-500',
    customBrdColor: 'border-custom-color-500',
    customTxtColor: 'text-custom-color-500',
  };

  const { customBgColor, customBrdColor, customTxtColor } = yourClassObj;

<YourComponent
   className={`mb-2 font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded-lg
      ${ conditionGoesHere ? `${customBgColor} text-white cursor-default`
                  : `${customTxtColor} border ${customBrdColor} 
                     bg-transparent hover:border-transparent 
                     hover:${customBgColor} hover:text-white`
              }`}
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

From [the Tailwindcss documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode)

> Dynamic values Note that you still need to write purgeable HTML when
> using arbitrary values, and your classes need to exist as complete
> strings for Tailwind to detect them correctly.
>
> Don't use string concatenation to create class names --> `<div className={`mt-[${size === 'lg' ? '22px' : '17px' }]`}></div>`
>
> Do dynamically select a complete class name --> `<div className={ size === 'lg' ? 'mt-[22px]' : 'mt-[17px]' }></div>`
> Tailwind doesn’t include any sort of client-side runtime, so class
> names need to be statically extractable at build-time, and can’t
> depend on any sort of arbitrary dynamic values that change on the
> client. Use inline styles for these situations, or combine Tailwind
> with a CSS-in-JS library like Emotion if it makes sense for your
> project.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to use the built in style property.

For example in React:

**Dont Use:**

```
className={`bg-[${color}]`}
```

**Use Instead:**

```
style={{
    backgroundColor: color,
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. This was solved by just using the **style** attribute with inline styles in **React JS**, which allows you to directly set the background color without relying on dynamically generated CSS classes or using Tailwind CSS JIT mode.

So just use,

```
    style={{backgroundColor:`${color}`}}
```

instead of,

```
    className={`bg-[${color}]`}
```