# MUI-Theming with Tailwind in className

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I want to use MUI theming in my otherwise Tailwind-styled page so I can centrally handle the color palettes for dark and light mode since I found the decentral dark and light mode theming provided by Tailwind not very practicable in case I want to change colors.

My approach is to use the Tailwind syntax for arbitrary values and pass the hex code from the theme.js color palette.

the Tailwind arbitrary syntax is:

```
bg-[#hex]
```

e.g.:

```
bg-[#50d71e]
```

which just works fine in normal classNames, e.g.:

```
    <div className={`bg-[#50d71e]`}>
    <div/>
```

gives me a green background (#50d71e) in that container.

On the other side, I have a mui-themed template page. Here I can reference colors as follows:

```
import {useTheme} from "@mui/material";
import { tokens } from "../../theme";

const AnyName = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

return (
<Box backgroundColor={colors.grey[400]}></Box>
<Box sx={{backgroundColor: colors.grey[500],}}></Box>
}
export default AnyName;
```

And again, it just works fine.

Now, if I want to fuse these two approaches, I am struggling to query the hex code out of the `const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);`.

The theme.js holds all color values as hex, so I think this should be possible. Here is a look inside:

```
export const tokens = (mode) => ({
    ...(mode === 'dark'
        ? 
        {
            grey: {
                900: "#141414",
                800: "#292929",
                700: "#3d3d3d",
                600: "#525252",
                500: "#666666",
                400: "#858585",
                300: "#a3a3a3",
                200: "#c2c2c2",
                100: "#e0e0e0",
            },
        } : {
            grey: {
                100: "#141414",
                200: "#292929",
                300: "#3d3d3d",
                400: "#525252",
                500: "#666666",
                600: "#858585",
                700: "#a3a3a3",
                800: "#c2c2c2",
                900: "#e0e0e0",
            },
         }),
      });
```

** What I have tried: **

```
const AnyName = ({ anyProp }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);

  return (
    <div
      className={`bg-[${colors.grey[400]}]`}
    ></div>
  );
};
export default AnyName;
```

This doesn't work. I guess it is a matter of scoping, but I am not sure, and I honestly do not know what I am doing.
So I tried a few more things like:

```
className={`bg-[{colors.grey[400]}]`}
```

Which doesn't seem to reference `colors` at all.
And:

```
className={`bg-[colors.grey[400]]`}
```

Which also does not reference `colors`.
All three approaches result in a transparent background.

Now I am here, hoping for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I also learned that there could be a work-around to this by pre-loading color-codes in the tailwind config js but I guess at that point it is just easier to define custom CSS class bundles without using tailwind and apply these dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this to work, But you are not able to see the `background color` because the there is `no children` for this `div`, which makes it `height` of 0

Try adding height:

```
 <div className={`bg-[${colors.grey[400]}] h-24`}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. Up there is not the complete code. I tried to keep it short for the post. There are children, and if I set the background using normal Tailwind syntax, e.g., bg-[#50d71e], it works as expected. Here is the full return statement, unmodified:

```
return (
    <div
      className={`bg-[#50d71e] shadow-lg rounded-lg p-0 lg:p-8 pb-12 mb-8`}
    >
      <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md pb-80 mb-6">
        <img
          src={post.featuredImage.url}
          alt={post.title}
          className="object-top absolute h-80 w-full object-cover shadow-lg rounded-t-lg lg:rounded-lg"
        />
      </div>
      <h1
        className="transition duration-700 text-center mb-8 cursor-pointer
        hover:[text-cyan-400] text-3xl font-semibold"
      >
        <Link href={`/post/${post.slug}`}>{post.title}</Link>
      </h1>
      <div className="block lg:flex text-center items-center justify-center mb-8 w-full">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-4 lg:mb-0 w-full lg:w-auto mr-8">
          <img
            alt={post.author.name}
            height="30px"
            width="30px"
            className="align-middle rounded-full"
            src={post.author.photo.url}
          />
          <p className="inline align-middle text-gray-700 ml-2 text-lg">
            {post.author.name}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="font-medium text-gray-700">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            className="h-6 w-6 inline mr-2 text-cyan-600"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke="currentColor"
          >
            <path
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              d="M8 7V3m8 4V3m-9 8h10M5 21h14a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z"
            />
          </svg>
          <span>{moment(post.createAt).format("DD. MMM, YYYY")}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="text-center text-lg text-gray-700 font-normal px-4 lg:px-20 mb-8">
        {post.excerpt}
      </p>
      <div className="text-center">
        <Link href={`/post/${post.slug}`}>
          <span className="transition duration-500 transform hover:-translate-y-1 inline-block bg-cyan-500 text-lg font-medium rounded-full text-white px-8 py-3 cursor-pointer">
            Continue Reading
          </span>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Since the VS Code autocompletion works as intended when using the $-approach, I guess maybe it is not or not only a matter of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around a bit more and found something strange.
In the following example I will be using `colors.grey[900]` which is `#141414`.
If I manually enter `bg-[#141414]`, the background will be dark-grey (obviously).
If I then enter `bg-[${colors.grey[900]}]`, it works just fine.
So I guessed, maybe that's just some caching.
I double-checked --> chrome --> F12 --> disable cache --> page refresh --> still works fine.
I double-checked again, differently by changing the hex to a different value, e.g. `bg-[${colors.grey[800]}]` --> doesn't work. Changing it back to `bg-[${colors.grey[900]}]` --> works again.
Checked it on a different Browser which always clears cache and never loaded the page before: still works.
Restart Server: and `bg-[${colors.grey[900]}]` also does not work anymore.

Steps to reproduce:

1. doesn't show grey background

```
    const AnyName = ({ anyProp }) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
      const hex = colors.grey[900];
    
      return (
        <div
          className={`bg-[${hex}]`}
        ></div>
      );
    };
    export default AnyName;
```

2. shows grey Background

```
    const AnyName = ({ anyProp }) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
      const hex = colors.grey[900];
    
      return (
        <div
          className={`bg-[#141414]`}
        ></div>
      );
    };
    export default AnyName;
```

3. shows grey Background

```
    const AnyName = ({ anyProp }) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
      const hex = colors.grey[900];
    
      return (
        <div
          className={`bg-[${hex}]`}
        ></div>
      );
    };
    export default AnyName;
```

4. doesn't show grey background (changed colors.grey to 800)

```
    const AnyName = ({ anyProp }) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
      const hex = colors.grey[800];
    
      return (
        <div
          className={`bg-[${hex}]`}
        ></div>
      );
    };
    export default AnyName;
```

5. shows grey background even in different browser without caching

```
    const AnyName = ({ anyProp }) => {
      const theme = useTheme();
      const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
      const hex = colors.grey[900];
    
      return (
        <div
          className={`bg-[${hex}]`}
        ></div>
      );
    };
    export default AnyName;
```

So I guess there must be some weird server-side binding issue that I overcome by once providing directly the correct value and afterwards it seems to be cached on server-side and works. Once I restart the server, everything is gone and I have to go through steps 1,2,3 to make it work again.

Any ideas? Workarounds also welcome.

edit:
I found this thread:

[JIT tailwindcss using variable in bg-[] not rendering color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289894/jit-tailwindcss-using-variable-in-bg-not-rendering-color)

Unfortunately, I did not find it before, even after reviewing related threads.
This sheds a lot of light on the issue.